# SSAS CUBE MISSING DATA

Tags: sql, ssas, ssas-2008, ssas-2012

I'm new to SSAS and can you guide me
I have Cube refresh fine no errors when checked cube last date update show todays date!

Also  verified dim_DateTime dimension where ReportingPeriod field show all months include 2018-02 & 2017-12 till year 2020…but no data coming only for these two months when run below mdx

```
 SELECT 
        Non Empty
         [Measures].[TotalCaseload] On Columns
        ,Non Empty
        [Dim_Team].[TeamDescription].AllMembers
        on ROWS
        From 
        [PbR_Caseload]
        Where 
        ([Dim_DateTime].[ReportingPeriod].[2017-12]
         , [Dim_Team].[PbRInScopeTeam].&[1])
```

When exec stored proc for months expect ‘2017-12’ & ‘2018-02’  but throws error when pass parameter as '2018-02'

exec [SSRS].[ds_ParmPbRCaseloadTeam]  '2018-01',1     refresh fine and gives data
exec [SSRS].[ds_ParmPbRCaseloadTeam]  '2018-02',1     throws below error

> An error occurred while executing the query.
>   A .NET Framework error occurred during execution of user defined routine or aggregate 'ExecuteOLAP': 
>   System.Exception: Column name or number of supplied values does not match table definition.
>   System.Exception: 
>      at OLAPExtensions.StoredProcedures.ExecuteOLAP(SqlString server, SqlString database, String MDX)
>   . User transaction, if any, will be rolled back.

Not sure what I’m missing?

Comment: Probably will need to see the sproc code.

Answer (score 0):

I occasionally found that we could add data to our data source, process all tables, and still have it not show up in the model.  We changed the **processing option** to 'Full', and that fixed the problem.  I don't know if this will help with yours or not, though.  Good luck!